# C++ const used twice in static array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, static, constants

I have seen `const` used twice in the declaration of a `static` array before and now that I am creating my own static array I am wondering why const would be needed twice in some situations.

Does having an array of pointers make a difference?

```
a. static const TYPE name[5];
b. static const TYPE const name[5];

c. static const TYPE* name[5];
d. static const TYPE* const name[5];
```

My understanding is that `b.` is invalid, but if using const twice is valid, what is its purpose?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
const TYPE* x;
```

Means that the thing that x points at is const.

```
TYPE* const x;
```

Means that the pointer x is const.

Combining the 2 you get:

```
const TYPE* const x;
```

Meaning the pointer and the thing pointed to are both const.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I will mark this correct tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply any cv-qualifier (`const` or `volatile`) to any type, including cv-qualified types -- yet not in the same declaration. However, they bind more strongly than any operator, in terms of precedence and can be applied on both sides of the qualified type:

```
// Let T by any type:
T const tr;
const T tl;
const T const tlr; // only in C
const const const const const T t5; // only in C
typedef const T CT;
CT const tcc; // fine, although CT was already const
```

declare exactly the same, a constant `T`. If `T` already has cv-qualifiers, this doesn't change the meaning of additional qualification.

Now, to the precedence; You can say "I want a pointer to a constant `T`":

```
const T (* tp);
```

which is usually written as

```
const T* tp;
```

because the `const` binds stronger than the `*` anyway. In the same pattern, you can define a variable that is "constant but points at a mutable `T`":

```
T (* const tp) = 0; // must be initialised, because tp is immutable
```

which is commonly written as

```
T* const tp = 0;
```

In the same vein the subscript operator `[]` is applied -- with the same precedence as in expressions.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block you have a redundant duplicate `const` in the second line, which has no effect. (In fact, good compilers will warn you about this.) You're declaring an array of 5 `const TYPE`s, that's it.

The second code block has two different scenarios: The first line makes an array of five *mutable* pointers to `const TYPE`s, while the latter makes an array of five *constant* pointers to `const TYPE`s.

Note that you must initialize an array of constants: Since you can't change the values later, it doesn't make sense to define them uninitialized.

Comment: Actually, you can throw as many `const`s at a type as you like. They're idempotent.

Comment: @bitmask: Oh OK, fixed. You'll get a compiler warning from sensible compilers, though :-) Thanks!

Comment: Ooops, I might have mixed C and C++ here. My bad.

Comment: @bitmask: I'm not totally sure now (I thought my compiler actually said it was illegal, but I'm not sufficiently bothered to dig up a standard reference), so I've toned down the language.

Answer (score 0):

Using `const` twice on a type is illegal in C++ 2003 but legal in C++ 2011 (see 7.1.6.1 [decl.type.cv] paragraph 1: "Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored."). When you used

```
static const TYPE const name[5];
```

you made `TYPE` constant twice. Note, however, that this declaration is illegal in C++ 2011, too, because you need initialize a `const` object when declaring it. The meaning of

```
const TYPE
```

and

```
TYPE const
```

is absolutely equivalent: In both cases you make the `TYPE` object constant. For consistency, I always put the `const` to the right because every except for the top-level type the `const` has to be put on the right side (well, unless some coding guideline mandates differently but I'm fighting silly coding guidelines).

When using pointers, thinks become different. There are two types involved: type pointed to type and the pointer. Each one of these can be made `const` separately:

```
TYPE const*       ptr1(0);  // non-const pointer to const TYPE
TYPE* const       ptr2(0);  // const pointer to non-const TYPE
TYPE const* const ptr3(0);  // const pointer to const TYPE
```

The best way to figure out what is made `const` is to read the type declaration from right to left. Of course, this assumes to that `const` qualifiers are put into the right location. You can replace `const` by `volatile` or `const volatile` in the discussion above and the same reasoning applies.